# Unable to move from one node to another in a doubly linked list in c

Tags: c, function, doubly-linked-list

Here's my code. I strongly believe that the issue is in the function list_next, it doesn't seem to be written correctly but I don't know any better on how else it should be written.

Code from the header file:

```
    The type for a node in the list.
struct node
{
struct node *next;
struct node *prev;
char *value;
};

// The type for a list.
typedef struct list
{
struct node head;
} List;

// The type for a list position.
typedef struct list_pos
{
struct node *node;
} ListPos;
```

And here's the function I'm having difficulty with in the main file:

```
ListPos list_next(ListPos pos)
{
struct node* node;
struct node *before = pos.node->prev;
struct node *after = pos.node;

node->next = after;
after->prev = node;

pos.node = node;
return pos;
}
```

Comment: The function has undefined behavior because the pointer node is uninitialized and does not make a sense.

Comment: `node->next = after;`, `node` is uninitialized, so dereferencing it with `node->` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Adele Also this declaration typedef struct list
{
struct node head;
} List; does not make a sense.

Comment: @yano Correct me if I'm wrong, but hasn't it been initialized by typing    struct node* node    ? I know that what I wrote in that function is wrong but I'm not sure what I can do to fix it.

Comment: no, that's wrong. There's nothing special about a pointer, it's a type that needs to be initialized to a value. If you do `int a; if (a < 5) { ... } else { ... };`, which branch will it take? You don't know, the value of `a` is undetermined. If you do `int a = 6;` instead, then you know exactly which branch it will take. `struct node* node;` is no different, simply declares a pointer called `node` of `struct node` type (kind of confusing, recommend using a more unique name), that points to _nothing_. So when you dereference it with the `->` operator, you invoke UB, which commonly segfaults.

Comment: You have _declared_ a `struct node` pointer, you haven't _initialized_ it to anything. You need to do `node = <something>` before dereferencing it with `->`, either with something like `node = malloc(...);` which reserves memory, or `node = structnodePointerThatAlreadyPointsToValidMemory;`. Or, you can initialize to NULL, `node = NULL`, but if you do that, you cannot dereference, since it doesn't point to a valid `struct node` object.